# Loading a storyboard from a framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, uistoryboard

I'm creating a library with Cocoapods and Swift 1.2. I have a storyboard that I have to load in my library. Although, I am always getting this same error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle`.

What I have tried:

- put my storyboard inside the `Classes` folder
- put my storyboard inside the `Assets` folder
- Delete my application from the device, clean the project and re-build.
- Use `UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)`
- Use `UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:NSBundle(forClass:self))`
- Use `UIStoryboard(name:"Main", identifier:myIdentifier)`

I was although able to load the storyboard from my example project, put then I was only able to instantiate the initial view controller.

Trying to invoke `storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(someIdentifier)` from the initial view controller always resulted in the view controller not being found, although I can clearly see that there is a view controller with that identifier. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `NSBundle(forClass:self)` ... is `self` a class in the same bundle as the storyboard?

Comment: @nhgrif Yes, it is. The storyboard file and the class are in the same folder.

Comment: Is the Storyboard added to the target? You can check this in the File inspector (in the right sidebar).

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, it is added to my target.

Comment: Can you possibly create a small project that reproduces the problem to post to github?

Comment: Hello, I want to do pretty much same thing but I didn't find any tutorial or good example so I can learn from it. Can you (or anyone else) help me please ? just by giving me a hint or some links .. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem. Just silly but after deleting the Main.storyboard from the project, I didn't remove it from the project's settings. Trying to load it as the initial view controller. After changing the settings, `UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:NSBundle(forClass:self)` just works properly.

Comment: for swift 5 you can use : Bundle(for:self)